# When is a .NET namespace implemented by a .NET Framework component?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

(Yet another question from my "Clearly I'm the only idiot out here" series.)

When I need to use a class from the .NET Framework, I dutifully look up the documentation to determine the corresponding namespace and then add a "using" directive to my source code:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Usually I'm good to go at this point, but sometimes Intellisense doesn't recognize the new class and the project won't build.  A quick check in the Object Browser confirms that I have the right namespace.  Frustration ensues.

Using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` involved adding the appropriate directive:

```
using System.Web;
```

But it also required adding a reference to .NET Framework Component for `System.Web`, i.e. right-click the project in Solution Explorer, select Add Reference and add System.Web from the .NET tab.

How might I discern *from the documentation* whether a .NET namespace is implemented by a .NET Framework Component that must be referenced?  I'd rather not hunt through the available components every time I use a namespace on the off chance that a reference is needed.

(For those who like to stay after class and clean the erasers: Will Organize Usings > Remove and Sort also remove references to componenents that are not used elsewhere in the project?  How do you clean up unnecessary references?)

Comment: <3 the first sentence. I feel like a contributor to that series from time to time.

Comment: It's good to know how to do this manually, but now that you know: just install ReSharper, type the name of a class you want to use and press Alt-Enter. It will auto-magically add the namespace *and* assembly references for you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check out this link for [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx):

> Namespace:  System.Web
>
> Assembly:  System.Web (in System.Web.dll)

The **Assembly** line tells you which dll to reference.

Answer (score 7):

You'll note that the documentation (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) tells you the name of the assembly/DLL that the class should be found in, along with the class's namespace.

> Namespace:  System.Web
>   Assembly:  System.Web (in System.Web.dll)

On a side note, I know it can be a little dear, but Resharper makes things like this so much easier. If you're a serious developer, you may want to consider investing in a license. For the eraser-cleaners, Resharper adds a handy little "Find Code Dependent on Module" item to the right-click menu on references in the Solution Explorer. It's not quite an automatic cleanup, but it makes it a lot easier to see whether something's still being used by your project.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation specifies two things for any type:

- The *namespace* of the type (for the using directive)
- The *assembly* containing the type (this is what you add a reference to)

To take an example where the two are different, look at the documentation for [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx):

> Namespace:  System.Linq
>   Assembly:  System.Core (in System.Core.dll)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the MSDN docs, e.g.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx

It tells you the namespace *and* the assembly that is required.

Answer (score 2):

First, a correction to your terminology:  What you are referencing is called an "assembly".  An assembly contains classes that belong to a namespace.  A namespace can span across multiple assemblies.

Most assemblies are named the same as the main namespace that is contained in them.  For example, `System.Web` exists in `System.Web.dll`.  The documentation also usually tells you which assembly needs to be referenced.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are running into a difference between c# and C here.  To compare:  In C, all you need to do to include a new library is to include it in the header.

It .net, you need to be aware of 2 things:

1. A namespace can span more than one assembly/dll  (that means that you might not get a compiler error on the using clause, because some of the dlls that support that namespace are referenced -- just not the one that you need)
2. To "see" the contents of a given assembly, you have to add a reference to it.  The using clause alone just gives you some short-cut syntax so that you can write HttpUtility.Encode(), instead of System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(), you have to add the reference in order for the compiler to "know" about the class.

To avoid your problem:

In the MSDN documents, pay attention to the assembly that the class is in, and make sure that you have a reference to the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

If you browse to the MSDN for the class you're trying to use. It typically tells you the assembly that the class is in. For example the [Regex class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) is in Assembly System (in System.dll) or the [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) class is in Assembly System.Web (in System.Web.dll).

I believe tools such as ReSharper help with this, as well, and automatically references the assemblies you need.

I'm pretty sure you have to manually remove the unused references in C# projects. In VB.NET projects there's a button to list the unused references when you're in the project properties page. I don't see this in C# projects, though.